# Python replacing column values with 0-x indexes (for xgboost)

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I'm using python (with pandas etc)
I have a data frame with label column (classes a,b,c, etc - 38 in total).
I want to use Xgboost for prediction, but it only works for lables in 0:num_classes range.

**So basically i need:**
 - to replace all values in label column with 0:num_class index (a with 0, b with 1, c with 2 etc)

The number of classes is 38, so mapping and replacing manually is not possible.
Is there an elegant way to do this?
(In R i would use:

```
train_data$Class <- as.numeric(factor(train_data$Class))
```

But it does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pandas.factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.factorize.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
df.Class = pd.factorize(df.Class)[0]
```

If you want backward you could store that variable and then reassign it:

```
factor = pd.factorize(df.Class)
# forward
df.Class = factor[0]
# backward
df.Class = factor[1]
```

Comment: Thanks!
And if i want to do a backward transformation after prediction is done?

Answer (score 2):

```
labels = ['a','b','a','c','b','a','c','a']
y = pandas.Series(labels)
unique_labels, y_inversed = numpy.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
print list(unique_labels[y_inversed]) == labels
```

result:
True

Answer (score 1):

For simple conversion you can use map method on your data frame,

```
df.class
Out[34]: 
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    c
5    b
6    a
Name: 0, dtype: object

df.class.map({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
Out[35]: 
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    2
6    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```